# how to input single quotation mark in a text in matlab

Tags: text, quotation-marks

trying to input the symbol ' - single quote inside a text will terminate the text. how to give the ' as input inside a text

> > a=';
> >      a=';
> >        |
> >     Error: String is not terminated properly.
> >
> > msg='asdfasdfasdf'asdfasdf';
> >      msg='asdfasdfasdf'asdfasdf';
> >                        |
> >     Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

In the first line i am trying to give single quote as input to a variable and in the next line i tried to give single quote in between. but both issues error. how can i solve this. kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in many other questions by googling for two seconds... Just use double apostrophe.

```
msg='abdabc''abcabc';
```

Or alternatively:

```
msg=strcat('abcabc', char(39), 'abcabc');
```

Comment: ya its working. Thank you for your answer. As a novice for matlab, i am unable to find out the solution for this.